# Extend a partition with nonadjacent space available

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I realise that there are similar questions out there, but I have read them everything I can find, and while they are generally helpful, they don't answer the question in my specific case. I'm still not sure how to proceed or even if I should!

I have a dual-boot system (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04) and have freed up 20GB of space. I want to expand my sda5 partition (which contains Ubuntu) using this unallocated space (with Gparted), but I don't know if this is possible as they are not adjacent - and sda5 is a logical partition and the unallocated space is not within an extended partition.

[image: Gparted]

I'm confused as how to proceed and the other answers I have seen are specific to the individual questions.

It seems like this might be a difficult thing to do and I may be better backing up and installing my operating systems from scratch? Is resizing this partition more trouble than it's worth?

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk appears to be partitioned using GPT and boots using EFI, so logical/extended partitions do not apply to you.  The only thing you need to do is boot from the livecd or usb, and move sda4 to the left, then move sda5 to the left, then grow sda5 to the right.  This should be quite easy using gparted from a livecd/usb.  The risk is in moving those two partitions to the left.  A power failure or crash while moving those partitions will destroy the data in them.  Hence, have a backup.